# Zooming in towards mouse in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

Is there a way to zoom towards where my mouse is in Ubuntu 16.04?
I am looking all over the default apps to find something to magnify where my mouse is.

Please, it would be great if I got an answer back.

Thank you!

Comment: Try looking under "Accessibility" or "Universal Access" preferences for something marked "magnifier" or "screen magnifier" or "zoom"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using KDE Plasma, use + to zoom in or - to zoom out. If you're not using Plasma then you can try xzoom which should already be installed on your system (search for it through the Dash) or start a terminal and type `xzoom`